# Отловить закрытие формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Нужно следующее: на странице есть всплывающая форма, при ее вызове, ее свойство display получает значение - block, при закрытии - становится none. Как можно отловить момент, когда пользователь закрывает форму?

Comment: Можете предоставить код, который закрывает саму форму?

Comment: закрытие формы это следствие, а отлавливать нужно причину, а именно клик, который приводит к закрытию формы

Comment: @MasterAlex Всё зависит от его кода. Можно повесить отслеживание `$('#myButton').click();`А можно просто в функции закрытия прописать то что нужно... Я потому и попросил подробности. Ибо зачем отслеживать клик, если можно в функцию закрытия прописать код. :)

Comment: Спасибо, код предоставить не могу, но понял все, что нужно